# How do I change the size of a GTK container widget?

Tags: python, gtk3, pygobject, gio

I'm getting myself thoroughly confused about how Gtk controls widget sizes inside a container such as a GtkBox.  Please can someone guide me through the intricacies for this question?

I have a GtkBox containing two widgets - in the example these are just two GtkButtons.

The first widget should just fill the space available inside the GtkBox container.

The second widget I want to force always to be a physical square - thus as the square enlarges, the first widget will shrink in terms of width.

Some example code will help here:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

def on_check_resize(window):
    boxallocation = mainbox.get_allocation()

    width = 0
    height = 0

    if boxallocation.height >= boxallocation.width:
        width = boxallocation.height
        height = width

    if boxallocation.width >= boxallocation.height:
        width = boxallocation.width
        height = width

    secondbtn_allocation = secondbtn.get_allocation()
    secondbtn_allocation.width = width
    secondbtn_allocation.height = height
    secondbtn.set_allocation(secondbtn_allocation)

win = Gtk.Window(title="Containers Demo")
win.set_border_width(10)
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)

mainbox = Gtk.Box()

firstbtn = Gtk.Button(label="just fills the space")
mainbox.pack_start(firstbtn, True, True, 0)
secondbtn = Gtk.Button(label="square")
mainbox.pack_start(secondbtn, False, True, 1)

win.add(mainbox)

win.connect("check_resize", on_check_resize)

win.show_all()

initial = firstbtn.get_allocation()
initial.height = initial.width
firstbtn.set_size_request(initial.width, initial.height)

Gtk.main()
```

When you expand the window - the GtkBox will likewise expand.  That's good.  The first button similarly also expands.  Good also.  However, the second button never is square even though I'm using the [set_allocation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.9/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-set-allocation) method for the GtkWidget.

I cannot use the set_size_request (or could I?) because when I shrink the window, the window cannot resize due to the altered  minimum size of the second button.

The reason why I'm trying to figure out how containers manage spacing is that I'm looking to eventually implement something like this iTunes example:

[image]

i.e. you can see the cover is always square - but the music details will shrink or expand to depending upon the space available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `Gtk.Box`, use `Gtk.Grid` and set the `hexpand` and `vexpand` properties on the buttons that you pack into the grid.

Also, consider using a [`Gtk.AspectFrame`](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/api/Gtk_3.0/classes/AspectFrame.html) for the square button.